# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eventClass' when reading a *.pkl file

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I use `pandas` library `(version pandas==1.0.3)` to read a pickle file but I keep getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eventClass'

data = pd.read_pickle(pth)
```

I tried older version of `pandas` library and still getting the same error.

Do you any suggestions please?

Comment: maybe try uninstalling and again install pandas

Comment: Already tried that, unfortunately, I am getting the same error.

Comment: How the pickle file was created? Is it coming from the same version of pandas? Same machine? Same python version? Or different (and in what way)?